# Make signed int value from unsigned int value and back

Tags: c++, c++17

I need to convert a sequence of unsigned integers to the sequence of signed integers and back keeping the order of the elements.

Ideally, i need functions like this

```
template <typename T>
std::make_signed_t<T> MakeSigned(T val);

template <typename T>
std::make_unsigned_t<T> MakeUnsigned(T val);
```

what is the right way to implement them?

**EDIT1:**

Functions MakeSigned and MakeUnsigned should satisfy the following criteria:

For a given pair of parameters a, b and return values a1, b1, if a <= b then a1 <= b1.

and for a given signed a

```
MakeSigned(MakeUnsigned(a)) == a
```

**EDIT2**:

MakeSigned does this (for a given type uint8_t, uint16_t, uint32_t, uint64_t):

```
0 => INT_MIN
UINT_MAX => INT_MAX
```

MakeUnsigned:

```
INT_MIN => 0
INT_MAX => UINT_MAX
```

Comment: Is the question how to implement the `MakeSigned` that you are declaring here? `return val;`

Comment: What are the `MakeSigned` and `MakeUnsigned` functions supposed to do? Negate the value (e.g. `return -val;`)? Plain conversion through casting (e.g. `static_cast<signed>(unsigned_value)`)? Or just set or clear the sign-bit? Something else? What should the result be of call each function with `0`? With `1`? With `-1`? With `UINT_MAX`? With `INT_MIN`?

Comment: @Barry this implementation does not keep the order, see EDIT1. Consider the pair of signed parameters -1, 0 of MakeUnsigned function.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude see EDIT2.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude if we set or clear the sign-bit we need the code depending on the endianness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would simply flip the sign bit:

```
template <typename T>
std::make_signed_t<T> MakeSigned(T val)
{
    return val ^ (1u << (sizeof(T) * 8 - 1));
}

template <typename T>
std::make_unsigned_t<T> MakeUnsigned(T val)
{
    return val ^ (1u << (sizeof(T) * 8 - 1));
}
```

Comment: What about endianness? Does this code work with both big/little endian?

Comment: @AlexeyStarinsky I believe it does.

Comment: Thanks! Nice functions! They compiles even better with 64 bit integers if I replace `1u` with `static_cast<T>(1)` For example, `MakeSigned(0ull)`

Comment: Instead of `8` - [`CHAR_BIT`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/climits) should be used.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to subtract/add bias term `std::numeric_limits<Signed>::min()` when mapping to/from `unsigned` types. The calculation must be done using unsigned arithmetics which wraps without producing undefined behaviour:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <limits>
#include <cstdint>

template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_unsigned_v<T>, std::make_signed<T>>::type map_to_signed(T val) {
    using U = std::make_signed_t<T>;
    return val + std::numeric_limits<U>::min(); // Wrapping unsigned addition. 
}

template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_signed_v<T>, std::make_unsigned<T>>::type map_to_unsigned(T val) {
    using U = std::make_unsigned_t<T>;
    return static_cast<U>(val) - std::numeric_limits<T>::min(); // Wrapping unsigned subtraction.
}

int main() {
    std::cout << map_to_signed(0u) << '\n';
    std::cout << map_to_unsigned(map_to_signed(0u)) << "\n\n";

    std::cout << std::numeric_limits<int>::max() << '\n';
    std::cout << map_to_unsigned(std::numeric_limits<int>::max()) << '\n';
    std::cout << map_to_signed(map_to_unsigned(std::numeric_limits<int>::max())) << "\n\n";

    std::cout << std::numeric_limits<unsigned>::max() << '\n';
    std::cout << map_to_signed(std::numeric_limits<unsigned>::max()) << '\n';
    std::cout << map_to_unsigned(map_to_signed(std::numeric_limits<unsigned>::max())) << "\n\n";

    std::cout << std::numeric_limits<uint64_t>::max() << '\n';
    std::cout << map_to_signed(std::numeric_limits<uint64_t>::max()) << '\n';
    std::cout << map_to_unsigned(map_to_signed(std::numeric_limits<uint64_t>::max())) << "\n\n";
}
```

Outputs:

```
-2147483648
0

2147483647
4294967295
2147483647

4294967295
2147483647
4294967295

18446744073709551615
9223372036854775807
18446744073709551615
```

Comment: What about the overflow with 64-bit integers?

Comment: @AlexeyStarinsky You may like to be more specific.

Comment: `std::is_signed_v<float> == true`

Comment: @AlexeyStarinsky `float` or `double` argument won't compile because `make_signed` and `make_unsigned` are defined for integers only.

Answer (score 0):

It's interesting that you do *not* have the requirement that these functions preserve the value of `a` and `b`. That's good, because if that were so, then they would not be implementable.

So you want to "offset" the values when you convert.

So `int(0)` becomes `unsigned(std::numeric_limits<int>::max()+1)`, and `unsigned(0)` becomes `std::numeric_limits<int>::min()`

With that, and Maxim's structure, you should be able to write the functions that you need.

Oh, and if you're using `INT_MIN` and `INT_MAX` instead of `numeric_limits`, you're going to fail.

Comment: Could You please complete the sentence "...you're going to fail" because ...?

Comment: `INT_MIN` etc are specific to `int`, while `numeric_limits` gives you the correct answer for whatever numeric type you're working with.